# My blender stoped to make subdivisions

Tags: modeling

When I press  + <2>, the program seems to work, but when I go to the sculpture tab, it just doesn't work, when I go to the edit mode that's what I see.

[image]

At some point I disabled subdivision, and I don't know how I did it or how to get back to normal

Comment: Apply the modifier in Object mode first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the subdivision surface modifier in order to actually get those extra vertices. As of now, you can only move and sculpt those 8 vertices.